Why does it getting stuck after calling the scheduler?
I'm trying to run a FreeRTOS task in an STM32F411RE board.
void my_task(void *pvParameters)
{
    while (1)
    {
            // Example:
            // Turn on LED
            // delay
            // Turn off LED
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    BaseType_t task_created = xTaskCreate(my_task, "my_task", 1024, NULL, 3, NULL);

    if (task_created != pdPASS)
    {
        // do something.
    }

    vTaskStartScheduler();
    return 0;
}

When the vTaskStartScheduler() is called, the function below that is in the timer.c is also called.
static portTASK_FUNCTION( prvTimerTask, pvParameters )
{
TickType_t xNextExpireTime;
BaseType_t xListWasEmpty;

        /* Just to avoid compiler warnings. */
        ( void ) pvParameters;
    
        #if ( configUSE_DAEMON_TASK_STARTUP_HOOK == 1 )
        {
            extern void vApplicationDaemonTaskStartupHook( void );
    
            /* Allow the application writer to execute some code in the context of
             * this task at the point the task starts executing.  This is useful if the
             * application includes initialisation code that would benefit from
             * executing after the scheduler has been started. */
            vApplicationDaemonTaskStartupHook();
        }
        #endif /* configUSE_DAEMON_TASK_STARTUP_HOOK */
    
        for( ; ; )
        {
            /* Query the timers list to see if it contains any timers, and if so,
             * obtain the time at which the next timer will expire. */
            xNextExpireTime = prvGetNextExpireTime( &xListWasEmpty );
    
            /* If a timer has expired, process it.  Otherwise, block this task
             * until either a timer does expire, or a command is received. */
            prvProcessTimerOrBlockTask( xNextExpireTime, xListWasEmpty );
    
            /* Empty the command queue. */
            prvProcessReceivedCommands();
        }
    }

The problem is when this function is called, it gets stuck in
prvProcessTimerOrBlockTask( xNextExpireTime, xListWasEmpty ); with xNextExpireTime = 0 and xListWasEmpty = 1.
Debuging using GDB, if I enter in the prvProcessTimerOrBlockTask and go step by step, it does not get stuck, and I can go to the next function prvProcessReceivedCommands();  but, when executing it, it also gets stuck.
Here are some configurations in FreeRTOSconfig.h
#define configCPU_CLOCK_HZ 100000000UL //100MHz
#define configSYSTICK_CLOCK_HZ (configCPU_CLOCK_HZ)
#define configTICK_RATE_HZ (100)
#define configUSE_TIMERS 1
#define configTIMER_TASK_PRIORITY (configMAX_PRIORITIES - 1)
#define configIDLE_SHOULD_YIELD 1
#define configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE ( ( unsigned short ) 128)
#define configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE    ( ( size_t ) ( 64 * 1024 ) )


You task will use all the procesor time as you do not pass any control to the sheduler. At lear add vTaskDelay(1) there.

Unfortunately, passing using vTaskDelay(n) using different values for 'n' didn't make a difference.

So your config is wong, invalid IRQ priorities, not working tick, stack problems + more
